# Checking my MySQL connection when using Python

Tags: python, mysql, filesystems, database-connection

I have a Python script which reads files into my tables in MySQL. Now this program runs automatically every now and then. However I'am afraid of 2 things:

1. Their might come a time the program stops running because it cant connect to the MySQL server. There are a lot of processes depending on this tables, so if the tables are not up to date the rest of my process will also stop working.
2. Their might sneak a file inside the process which does not have the expected content. After the script finished running, every value of column X must have 12 rows. If it does not have 12 rows this means the files did not have the right content inside them.

**My question is:** Is there something I can do to tackle this before it happens? Like send an e-mail to myself so I can be notified if the connection fails or like run the program on another server or if a certain value has like NOT 12 rows?

I'm very eager to know how you guys handle this situations.

I have a very simple connection made like this:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host= 'localhost',
        user = 'root',
        passwd = '*****.',
        database= 'my_database'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The event you are talking about is very unlikely to happen, and the only possible situation I could see this happening is when your database runs out of memory. For which you can set up a 2 min period every 2 to 3 days when you will go and check the amount of memory left in your server.

Comment: If you are using a local server then go to system storage and see how much storage you have left.

Comment: If you are using a cloud server then you will have to tell me which website you are using.

Comment: No you don't add that to your code you just go and check it manually, every 2 to 3 days.